# How to echo message in a foreach loop once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Let say I have a query like this:

```
    foreach ($emailist AS $addy) {
     if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
    echo "Mail Sent";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "e";
    }   
  }
```

and I have a jquery that call the response

```
success :  function(data)
{
if(data=="Mail Sent")
{
$("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
$("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-success"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Successfully Sent!!</div>');
$("#btn-submit").html('<span class="fa fa-check"></span> &nbsp; Sent');

});
}
else if(data=="e")
{
$("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
$("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-success"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Saved only to database and mail not sent!!</div>');
$("#btn-submit").html('<span class="fa fa-check"></span> &nbsp; Sent');

});
} }
```

How can I make **Mail Sent** to echo once in such loop?

I have tried everything I could but to no avail. Everytime I run the program **Mail Sent** appareared number of time the program loop instead of **Successfully Sent!!** in the ajax response.

Comment: The question I have is why are you looping if you only want to echo once?

Comment: @Taplar, because I explode the email addresses and loop in order to send to multiple users at once.

Comment: Agreed with @Taplar 1000%. You are not even using `$addy` in your loop.

Comment: @Taplar, I used $to to hold the $addy.

Comment: @TonyeBoro did you mean to tag Monkey with that comment?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like perhaps you are trying to see if all the emails were sent successfully?

```
$errorsExist = false;

foreach ($emailist AS $addy) {
    //errors exist if the email fails now, or did in the past
    $errorsExist = !@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) || $errorsExist;
}

if ($errorsExist) {
    echo "e";
} else {
    echo "Mail Sent";
}
```